# Best Voice Compression Algorithms/Formats

Tags: audio, compression

We have some raw voice audio that we need to distribute over the internet. We need decent quality, but it doesn't need to be of musical quality. Our main concern is usability by the consumer (i.e. what and where they can play it) and size of the download. My experience has shown that mp3s do not produce the best compression numbers for voice audio, but I am at a loss for what the best alternatives are. Ultimately we would like to automate the conversion process to allow the consumer to choose the quality vs. size level that they would like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Start here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_encoding)

As you rightly point out, voice compression is different from general audio compression.  You'll find many codecs dedicated to telephony applications, ranging from PCM and ADPCM through later packet based encodings such as CELP used on GSM cellular networks.

Still, VOIP voice encoding is slightly different from that due to the medium used.  you can find a good, free (unencumbered and open source (BSD)) library for speech encoding/decoding in the [Speex software library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speex).

Again, which you choose depends on the speech you're encoding and the medium it's being transmitted over.  Also note that many libraries have several algorithms they can use depending on the circumstances, and some will even switch on the fly based on conditions of the sound and network.

To get more help, narrow your question down.

-Adam

Comment: For anyone coming across this since 2008, [Opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)) has replaced Speex.

Answer (score 6):

You should give [Opus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_%28codec%29) a try. Example compression command line:

```
ffmpeg -i x.wav -b:a 32k x.opus
```

Answer (score 1):

The most frequently used compression formats used in live voice audio (like VoIP telephony) are μ-Law (mu-Law/u-Law is used in the US) and a-Law (used in Europe, etc.) which, unlike Uncompressed PCM, don't support as wide of a frequency range (a smaller range of possible values ignores sounds outside of the necessary spectrum and requires less space to store).

For usability sake it is easiest to use mpeg compressions (mp2/3/4) for streaming to standard media players as the algorithms are readily available and typically quite fast and almost all media players should support it, but for voice you might try to specify a lower bitrate or do your conversion from a lower quality file in the first place (WAV can be at several sampling rates and voice requires a much lower sampling rate than music or effects, it's basically like frame-per-second on video). Alternatively you can use Real Media, WMA or other proprietary formats, but this would limit usability since the users would require specific third party software for playback, though WMA has an excellent compression ratio as well as compression options specific to voice audio.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your users will be running Windows, there is a WMA speech compression codec that you can use with the Windows Media Encoder SDK. Failing that, you can use ACM to use something like G723/G728, ADPCM, mu-law or a-law, some of which are installed as standard on Windows XP & above. These can be packaged inside WAV files. You'll need to experiment a little to find the right bitrate/quality (probably don't bother with mu-law or a-law). With voice data you can get away with quite low sample rates - e.g. 16000 or 8000, as there isn't much above 4Khz in the human spoken voice.

Answer (score 0):

I think [AMR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Multi-Rate) is one of the best speech codecs. I was using it about a year ago and I remember that quality was very good and size levels were rather small.

One drawback, especially in your case is that, as far as I know, it isn't supported by wide range of media players. QuickTime and RealPlayer are two which I know to play .amr files.

Answer (score 0):

Try [speex](http://speex.org/) ... unencumbered by patents, good performance both sizewise and CPU-wise. I've been having good luck using it on iPhone.